# is it actually possible to send binary XHR request using .send()?

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

is it actually possible to send binary XHR request using `.send()`? *NOT* using `.sendAsBinary()` (which is poorly supported anyway). My approach so far looks like this:

```
var data    = base64_decode(image);

// photo file
var part = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="me.jpg"' + CRLF + "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + CRLF + CRLF + data + CRLF;

//console.log( base64_encode(element.files[0].getAsBinary()) );

parts.push(part);

// prepare the query
var request = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary + CRLF + CRLF; 
    // content-length is missing    
    request += "--" + boundary + CRLF;
    request += parts.join("--" + boundary + CRLF);
    request += "--" + boundary + "--" + CRLF;

// send the data
var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();

//xhr.open('post', 'photos_upload.php', true);
xhr.open('post', '/trash/upload.php', true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', String(request.length));

xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.responseCode === 200)
    {
        var response            = xhr.responseText;
        var temp                = response.match(/photo.php\?fbid=(\d+)/)[1];
        var temp2               = response.match(new RegExp(temp + '_(\\d+)_(\\d+)'));
        var photo_id            = temp2[1];
        var photo_pid           = temp2[2];

        var friends_for_tags    = array_chunk(friends, number_of_tags)[0];

        for(i in friends_for_tags)
        {
            if(friends_for_tags.hasOwnProperty(i))
            {
                tag_photo(photo_id, photo_pid, friends_for_tags[i].text, friends_for_tags[i].uid);
            }
        }
    }

};

console.log(request);

xhr.send(request);
```

`image` is base64 encoded image file. However, this is what `$_FILES` return on server side:

```
array(1) {
  ["file1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "me.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(3)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

This is how the XHR request looks in the `console.log`:

````
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------1303767479498 -------------------------------1303767479498 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo" bar -------------------------------1303767479498 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="me.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg PNG  ��� IHDR���������wSÞ���IDATc```����£ ã����IEND®B` -------------------------------1303767479498--
````

Comment: If you already have access to the base64 encoded image, why don't you send the base64 data to your server and decode it server-side?  It seems like that would simplify your client-side javascript code?

Comment: I don't have control over the remote server, @Chris.

Comment: If the image is base64 encoded already, you should set the Content-Transfer-Encoding field to base64 for that part.  If the server-side knows how to properly parse multipart/form-data posts, it should properly decode the part into its binary form before passing the data to application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues that I see.

First, I am not able to successfully set the Content-Length header from script.  I get error messages in Chrome when I attempt this.  It looks like it is not necessary anyway, as the browser is setting the correct content-length for all of my test cases.

Secondly, you are adding a Content-Type header, and you are putting a Content-Type faux-header into your request body:

```
var request = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary + CRLF + CRLF;
```

That line should be removed. You are already setting the correct header.  You cannot actually set headers in the body anyway.  This is probably the source of your problem: this line is making your request body invalid, so of course the server cannot parse it.

After some experimentation, I have developed a [working example](http://chris.photobooks.com/tests/so/5783545/5783545.html) of how this might be done.  I've tested this in Chrome latest, Firefox 4, IE9 and IE6.  No libraries have been used, though of course, if you have them, it would greatly simplify the code.

Please let me know if you find any issues.